# Why is cookie authentication is success even after I deleted the DataProtectionProvider Key from directory in aspnetcore 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, data-protection, cookie-authentication

I'm looking to implement cookie authentication that work in a multi server environment/webfarm.when I tested this with Dataprotection provider persistkeystofilesystem mapped to a local folder,the key gets created and cookie is also autheticated but when I deleted the key from folder still the cookie is getting validated true.What I expect is if a cookie is protected with the key then after deleting that key authentication should not work.Am I missing any core/basic functionality of aspnetcore.

...
.AddCookie(opt=>{
opt.DataProtectionProvider=DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys"));
});

...

what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you restart the server after deleting key? I would assume key is cached in memory.

Comment: Thank you very very much @Noah Stahl :). After Recycling App Pool it is working as expected.